# How to perform some action when a user touches anywhere that isn't a link/anchor etc?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using html/javascript with iOS and UIWebView.
I want to invoke an objective-c method when the user touch anywhere on the page that isn't a link.

At the moment I have

```
...

<BODY ontouchend="bodyTouch();">
<HEAD>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function bodyTouch() {
            invokeObjectiveC();
            }
        }
     </script> 

...
<DIV id=buttons>
<A id=navigator href="CustomScheme:SomeAction"></A>
....
```

How can I set things up so that bodyTouch() only gets invoked if the user touches anywhere on the screen that *isn't* a link/button/anchor etc.

==== Update ===

Thanks for lots of answers folks.
Unfortunatly I couldn't get any of them to work (now my InvokeObjectiveC() doesn't get called at all when I try any of them).
I'm an iOS developer and don't know html/javascript. I'll do a bit of studying as I don't understand any of the answers at the moment with my limited knowledge, then try them once I understand what they are doing and try to figure out why its not working.
I'll mark one of the answers as accepted in due course.
Cheers

Comment: is it InvokeObjectC that does not work, or our answers?

Comment: I could get invokeObjectiveC() to be invoked and in turn for it to invoke the Objective-C code it calls with my originally posted code all successfully, but the invokeObjectiveC() function doesn't appear to be being invoked in the first place with these answers.

Comment: try using the "touch" event, not the click event. I think we are all testing in desktops

Comment: That didn't seem to work either - do I just put the posted code in the <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> section? And I'm presuming I remove the ontouchend="bodyClick();" part, or not? I also tried with ontouchstart and ontouchend which seem to be apple specific?

Comment: Not getting any luck with that - but I need to apologize, in my posting I originally said click when I meant touch. I changed 'click' to 'touch' or 'ontouchdown' but without luck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7888/discussion-between-woofbeans-and-roderick-obrist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this one a shot, you should be able to place this anywhere in the document

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

  /* CHECK IF THE TARGET IS IN YOUR BANLIST */
  if (['A', 'BUTTON'].indexOf(e.target.tagName) === -1) {

   /* I WOULD CALL THESE FOR GOOD MEASURE */
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();

   /* THIS IS YOUR FUNCTION */
   invokeObjectiveC();
  }
 }, true);
}, false);
</script>
```

this does not work on the input[type=button] looking buttons, if you need that as well let me know

Comment: ?? he is invoking objective C?... how many browsers can you do that from?(safari only)

Comment: Thanks Roderick. Actually its not from within Safari - its not possible to invoke arbitrary native iOS functionality from within Safari. Its from within a native iOS app that uses a UIWebView (this is an iOS object that provides web like functionality) to display web pages. Using this and doing some tricks its possible for Objective-C to call html/Javascript and vice versa.

Comment: Does it not use the mobile safari engine? ... I need to know this actually because my next project more or less involves something similiar to what your doing.

Comment: They're both based on the same underlying stuff - but they do actually use different Javascript engines, and Safari code is sandboxed off from iOS code. Safari exposes a tiny bit of iOS functionaly but if you want to get at more native iOS functionality you have no option but to make it a native (or "hybrid") iOS app. If this is something you'll be doing drop me a private mail if you like if you might need some guidance. Calling javascript from Objective-C and loading a html page in iOS is easy, but calling Objective-C from Javascript  requires some hoop jumping  and good knowledge of iOS.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to pm you Woofbeans, I might have some work for you. can you PM me?

Comment: Maybe its not possible, strange I would have thought it was a feature of the site. Are you on linkedin etc.?

Comment: Got this working now, thanks. P.S. its possible to move comments to a chat room, the comment thread from the first posting has been moved.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   bodyClick();
}, false);
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

​
Learn more about [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) at Mozilla Developer Network

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7xN8/)

Comment: anywhere that isnt a link?, plus calling stop propagation does nothing when the body is the second last element on the chain

Comment: Yes you are right `stopPropagation` should applied to `a` not body because `body` is behind all `a`s

Comment: this has major performance issues. if a page has 100 A elements, you just added 100 event listeners when you can do the entire thing in one function

Comment: @RoderickObrist I believe your answer is better. I just wanted to explain how `stopPropagation` actually works.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery delegate and selector, 
but be careful if the original element trigger that event  uses  stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Roderick's response, but a bit more cross-browser friendly

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    var el, elN;
    ev = ev || window.event;
    el = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
    elN = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (elN == 'a' || elN == 'input') return false;
    invokeObjectiveC();
}, true);
```

Comment: if the body has a margin on it then there is space inbetween <html> and <body> elements, that means that clicking on the html element, which is possible, will not provide a click event to the <body> element.

Imagine if the body height was 0, but the html element height was 100%. then the body would never get the click event

Comment: @RoderickObrist that's true, I hate it when designers do that! Fixed.